# I have a mobile website but it loads zoomed out. How can I fix this?

Tags: html, mobile, zooming, mobile-website

I have a mobile website but it loads zoomed out. How can I fix this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should insert the Viewport meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

> This means that the browser will (probably) render the width of the
>   page at the width of its own screen. So if that screen is 320px wide,
>   the browser window will be 320px wide, rather than way zoomed out and
>   showing 960px (or whatever that device does by default, in lieu of a
>   responsive meta tag).

Reference: [Css-Tricks - Responsive Meta Tag](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)  -  [MDN - Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Answer (score 3):

You might need to set the **viewport**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/viewport-metatag/